# Why if I run method one time is done work almost the same time if I run few times in for loop c#

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I make one method who doing some simple operations like +, -, *, /.
I need to run this method 1513 times.

Here I try to run this method only once. To see do is working good and how times is be needed for to finish with operations.

```
Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();
st.Start();
DiagramValue dv = new DiagramValue();
double pixel = dv.CalculateYPixel(23.46, diction);
st.Stop();
```

When is stop the stopwatch is teling me the time is 0.06s.

When I run the same method 1513 times in for loop like that:

```
Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();
st.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 1513; i++)
{
    DiagramValue dv = new DiagramValue();
    double pixel = dv.CalculateYPixel(23.46, diction);
}
st.Stop();
```

Then the Stopwatch is tell me is working around 0.14s. Or 0.14s / 1513 times = 0.00009s for one time.

My question is why If I running some method only once is too slow and if I running around thousand times in for loop is almost the same time.

Comment: it could be that initializing the stopwatch (or some other part of the program) is what is taking the most amount of time, that the actual operation that is being measured is trivial. Would need to see the full program in order to see what is actually happening.

Comment: Where do you declare and use the stopwatch?

Comment: @user1666620: Initializing the stopwatch would not take 60 ms, but I imagine there is some sort of static initialization going on.

Comment: Also what is DiagramValue? Without a full view of what's going on this questions can't really be answered

Comment: @StriplingWarrior you're right, but then again we can't tell unless we see the rest of the program.

Comment: @Liam is not important what is doing DiagramValue. Is some class and is doing some simple operation. And I edit my code to see how I declare the stopwatch.

Comment: You could do a more interesting test by changing your loop code to `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)`, and then setting the value of N to 0, 1, 1000 and 1000000. Does the stopwatch increase when you change N=0 to N=1? To N=1000? To N=1000000? (Note: Test all the cases using a loop, even the most simple ones N==0 and N==1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writing benchmarks is hard.

First, `Stopwatch` isn't infinitely accurate. When you run the method just once, you're very much limited by the accuracy of the underlying stopwatch. On the other hand, running the method multiple times alleviates this - you can get arbitrary precision by using a big enough loop. Instead of 1 vs 1513, compare e.g. 1500 vs. 3000. You'll get around 100% time increase, as expected.

Second, there's usually some cost with the first call in particular (e.g. JIT compilation) or with the memory pressure at the time of the call. That's why you usually need to do "preheating" - run the method outside of the stopwatch first to isolate these, and measure (multiple invocations) later.

Third, in a garbage collected environment like .NET, the guy who ordered the beer isn't necessarily the guy who pays the bill. Most of the cost of memory allocation in .NET is in the collection, rather than the allocation itself (which is about as cheap as a stack allocation). The collection usually happens outside of the code that caused the allocations in the first place, pointing you in the entirely wrong direction when searching for performance issues. That's why most .NET memory trackers display garbage collection separately - it's important to take account of, but can easily mislead you as to the cause if you're not careful.

There's many more issues, but these should cover your particular scenario well enough.

Comment: So perfectly answered.

Answer (score 4):

Some possible reasons include:

1. Timing resolution. You get a more accurate figure when you find the mean over a large number of iterations.
2. Noise. The percentage of stuff that isn't what you actually want to record, will be different.
3. Jitting. .NET will create code the first time a method is used. As such the first time it is run in a programs lifetime, the longer it will take, by a large factor (try running it once and then measuring the second attempt).
4. Branch prediction. If you keep doing the same thing with the same data the CPU's branch predictor is going to get better at predicting which branches are takken.
5. GC stability. Not likely in this case, but possible. Often at the start of a set of operations that requires particular objects to be created and then released the program ends up having to get more memory from the OS. When it's a bit into that set of operations it's more likely to have reached a steady state where it can just get that memory by cleaning out objects it isn't using any more, which is faster.